# Slow booting + weird resolution

Tags: boot, dual-boot, display-resolution, boot-repair

I’ve just recently installed Ubuntu on HP Omen 15 and suddenly its boot time increased(lasts about 100 seconds or more) and while booting resolution changes (which hasn’t happened before). I’ve looked up a bit and learned there may be numerous reasons of slow booting. But how about weird resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a low resolution? If so you're graphics card driver is probably not working or loaded into the kernel. If you have an nvidia card add the nvidia apt repository, install drivers, and reboot.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430 # pick the version you want
sudo reboot now
```

If that doesn't work maybe reinstall your kernel.

```
uname -r # find out your current kernel
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-<your kernel>
```